# Dictionaries and why I keep printing every result

Tags: python, dictionary, process

So I wrote a piece of code to detect the lowest temperature in a city depending on what the input was, my problem right now is that I am getting each individual result from each process of the loop. So instead of one final print statement with the weather and city I end up with

```
[(-3, 'Toronto')]
The coldest city is: Toronto -3
[(-5, 'Edmonton'), (-3, 'Toronto')]
The coldest city is: Edmonton -5
[(-5, 'Edmonton'), (-4, 'Calgary'), (-3, 'Toronto')]
The coldest city is: Edmonton -5
```

with my input being Toronto, -3 Edmonton -5, Calgary -4

This is my code

```
dic = {}
for i in range(5):
        city = input("Enter city followed by temperature >")
        if (city != "stop"):       
                info = city.split()
                dic[info[0]] = int(info[1])
        elif city == "stop":
                break
print(dic) 
alist=[] 
for k,v in dic.items(): 
        alist.append((v,k)) 
        alist.sort() 
        print(alist)
        temp = alist[0]
        print("The coldest city is:",temp[1], temp[0])
```

Comment: You have `print` statement in a loop. What else could you possibly expect?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: In addition, you already have a dict, so work with it directly. There is no reason to create `alist`, no reason to sort it every iteration of the loop and no reason to update temp.

Answer (score 2):

Move everything except the `append` outside the loop, so it get executed only one time, after all the data is inside the `alist`:

```
for k,v in dic.items(): 
    alist.append((v,k)) 
alist.sort() 
print(alist)
temp = alist[0]
print("The coldest city is:",temp[1], temp[0])
```

Comment: The three lines before that should also be outside the loop.

Comment: Haha, thank you so much. I cannot believe I stressed over that for an hour and I missed the indentation in my print statement. I appreciate it.

Comment: @user2767528 you also have to move everything else except the `append` outside the loop.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out too the second you pointed out the print statement lol. Thank you

Comment: Ah.. The code was right, i wasn't! Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You should append all the items first and then apply sort:

```
alist=[] 
for k,v in dic.items():
    alist.append((v,k)) 
alist.sort() 
print(alist)
temp = alist[0]
print("The coldest city is:",temp[1], temp[0])
```

Or a shorter version will be to use `min`, this will take `O(N)` time(No need of sorting).:

```
min(dic, key=dic.get) #Returns the key with smallest value
min(dic.items(), key = lambda x:x[1]) #return key, value pair
```

Comment: Thank you, It makes sense too. I need to append everything then look through what I've appended and sort. I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @user2767528 There's no need to use `sort` here, simply use `min`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a `dict` at all? A `list` or a `set` might make more sense

```
cities = []
for i in range(5):
    city = input("Enter city followed by temperature >")
    if city == "stop":
        break
    info = city.split()
    cities.append((int(info[1]), info[0]))

print("The coldest city is: {} {}".format(*min(cities)))
```